# How to run Multiple HTTP samplers inside the IF controller

Tags: jmeter

I've one scenario where there are two http samplers inside the if controller

When the if condition is true , its only running the first HTTP sampler.Its not executing the HTTP sampler2.

```
as example:- 
if-controller ( condition true, none of the check-box got checked)
  ++HTTP sampler1
  ++HTTP sampler2
```

output :- only HTTP sampler1 runs . It never execute the sampler2 even if the sampler 1 result is pass state

I know I can split it into two if-controllers which would work fine. but I don't want that. Because if I have say 5 HTTP samplers to execute on basis of if-controller then I shouldn't split that to 5 if-controllers each embed with individual HTTP sampler.

```
if-controller ( condition true, none of the checkbox got checked)
   ++HTTP sampler1
if-controller ( condition true, none of the checkbox got checked)
   ++HTTP sampler2
```

Is there a way I can club all HTTP samplers underneath IF-controller and execute. I tried with simple controller but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If Controller will run all its children samplers .
Which version of JMeter are you using ? Are you sure they do not run ?
Show you Test Plan, and the 2 samplers configuration.

I have just tested it with 2.9, no problem.

It seems you have an issue in your If Controller condition

> ${reservationCode} != null && ${serviceId} != null && ${code} != null

Should be:

> "${reservationCode}" != "null" && "${serviceId}" != "null" && "${code}" != "null"

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. However there is no error in the log file. Still the HTTP sampler2 doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

It was my silly mistake :-). I've added the if controller insider the for controller to run few http samplers and then exit from for loop . However to exit from for loop I've added BSF post processor which was causing problem as after running the first http sampler inside if condition, then BSF postprocssor was getting invoked and it was exiting from the for loop. So it was not executing the second http sampler inside if loop. I changed the bsf post processor to bsf sampler and it worked fine.

```
 for loop
    if condition 
       http sampler 1
       http sampler 2
       BSF post processor for exit from for loop
```

Changed to

```
 for loop
    if condition 
       http sampler 1
       http sampler 2
       BSF Sampler for exit from for loop
```